# Index was outside the bounds of the array. even though i tried to stop it

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception

```
while (worldY != WorldHeight) { //3rd pass (Filling in rough terrain)
    while (worldX != WorldWidth) {
        if (worldY > 0) {
            if (world[worldX, worldY-1] == 1) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1; }
            if (worldX > 0) {
                if (world[worldX-1, worldY-1] == 1) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1; }
            }
            if (worldX < WorldWidth) {
                if (world[worldX+1, worldY-1] == 1) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1; }
            }
        }
        if (worldX > 0) {
            if (world[worldX-1, worldY] == 1) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1; }
        }
        if (worldX < WorldWidth) {
            if (world[worldX+1, worldY] == 1) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1; }
        }
        worldX++;
    }
    worldX = 0;
    worldY++;
}
```

I'v been cracking at this for a while, asked my friends & the internet about it but why every time it reaches here it ignores my initial if statements and goes straight for the ones i don't want it to be at yet just keeps giving me an `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
even though i put code that looks like it should prevent that.

any suggestions? or alternate code?

Comment: Suggestion, past some sample data, and the initialization , and what you expect the output to be, also those hanging brackets and one-line `if`s just make it all the more confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If think the problem is in the lines with logic like this:

```
if (worldX < WorldWidth) {
    if (world[worldX+1, worldY] == 1) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1; }
}
```

Here you are checking if `worldX` is less than `WorldWidth` and then using `worldX + 1`. But this is not safe. Consider the case when `WorldWidth` is 6 and `worldX` is 5. Then you the check goes through just fine, but `worldX + 1` then is 6 and causes `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The correct way to handle this would then be:

```
if ((worldX + 1) < WorldWidth) {
    if (world[worldX+1, worldY] == 1) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1; }
}
```

The same problem is present twice in your code, so once you fix those occurences, it should work as expected.

Also as a suggestion, I would suggest using `while (index < length)` instead of `while (index != length)`. Although both work in this case, if you later decided to increment index by two for some reason, you could get into an infinite loop if the index just happened to skip the exact value of length.

Comment: Woah you have better eyes then me, mine just glazed over. Upvote

Comment: Thanks it worked well for me. ps. while i have been programming for a while i'm not the best or most efficient so i normally go with what i know.

Comment: No problem with that, learning takes time :-) . Happy coding!